# How to set a KDE KWin custom keyboard shortcut that includes the caret key (circumflex)

Tags: kde, kde5

I'm running Fedora 38 with KDE Plasma 5.27.6.
I have a German keyboard and want to define a custom keyboard shortcut for KWin's 'Walk Through Windows of Current Application' with key combination `ALT+^` (caret/circumflex), but this doesn't work and shows up strange in System Settings -> Shortcuts: `Alt+ោ?`

Other key combinations like `CTRL+TAB` work fine. But on a German keyboard the caret/circumflex key is directly above the TAB key, so that when switching between applications using `ALT+TAB` I don't have to reposition my fingers to switch between windows of the current application which I like a lot.

I guess caret/circumflex is special because you have to press and release the key and then type an additional letter to get something like `ê` ...

However, is there any way to use the caret/circumflex key in KDE keyboard shortcuts with a German keyboard ?